# PHP/sql questionnaire & suitability matching

Tags: php, mysql, matching

I am developing a solution for matching people with certain things they might be interested in using a questionnaire done with PHP and mySQL. Basically a user answers questions, it creates a profile of the user, and then compares this to certain things in the DB that might suit their personality. It's not a dating site, but I guess it would work similar to how a dating website works where people do a questionnaire and it can match them based on these with a % match value.

I have started developing this, but am thinking the method I am using may not be the most efficient. I would like that you could sort your matches by your best match.

Any suggestion what the best method for doing this is?

Thanks, 
Declan

Answer (score 1):

Concat the answers into a string. It looks a little like binary if they are yes/no, but there's no harm in using other numbers, or hex, or pairs if you have >16 and <100 options, or use a divider etc etc.

To find the closest match compare each character in each position and rank the result.

**rank = the amount of characters that are the same in the given comparison string**, e.g. "0101101001"

```
0101101001 against 0101101001 gives a rank of 10 
0101101001 against 1101101001 gives a rank of 9
0101101001 against 1111111001 gives a rank of 7
0101101001 against 0001100111 gives a rank of 6
```

As SQL

```
table `yesno`
| user_id | answers    |
|    1    | 0101101001 |
|    2    | 1101101001 |
etc

SELECT answers,
    ( #looking for 0101101001
    IF (substring(answers,1,1)=0, 1, 0) 
    + IF (substring(answers,2,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,3,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,4,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,5,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,6,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,7,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,8,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,9,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,10,1)=1, 1, 0)
    ) 
AS rank
FROM yesno 
ORDER BY 
    ( #looking for 0101101001
    IF (substring(answers,1,1)=0, 1, 0) 
    + IF (substring(answers,2,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,3,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,4,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,5,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,6,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,7,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,8,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,9,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,10,1)=1, 1, 0)
    ) 
DESC
```

As PHP

```
#usage $rs=getUsersByRank("0101101001");

function getUsersByRank($lookslike) {
    /* expects "binary" string
    returns user_id, answers and rank (0 to string length) ordered by closest match first 
    */  

    $ifs=array();
    foreach (str_split($lookslike) as $i=>$bit){
        $ifs[]='IF (substring(answers,' . ($i+1) . ',1)=' . $bit . ', 1, 0) ';
    }

    // use your db class
    return $db->select_many('
        SELECT user_id, answers,
            ( '. implode(' + ', $ifs) .' ) 
        AS rank
        FROM yesno 
        ORDER BY 
            ( '. implode(' + ', $ifs) .' ) 
        DESC
    ');
}
```

You would need another table to store user1, user2, match_rank if you want to keep the comparisons of each user with each other user.

You might like to limit the results in getUsersByRank().

*I haven't actually tested that this works, just written it out.*